Can the JSS import service be used on a Sitecore CD server?
I am setting up a CI/CD pipeline for our Sitecore project and encountering an issue when attempting to use the JSS deploy app command on the CD server. The command works fine on the CM server, but we are seeing errors when running it on the CD server.
From my analysis, it appears that the JSS deploy app command relies on the /sitecore/api/jss/import endpoint, which is available on the CM server but not on the CD server. Since the import endpoint is used for deploying items and files, it seems that it's not necessary or even appropriate to use this on the CD server.
Can anyone confirm if the JSS App import service should only be run on the CM server? Is there a specific reason why it shouldn't be used on the CD server?
Thank you for your help!

The Import Service is automatically disabled on CD servers as per the documentation mentioned in Sitecore import service .

You can look into this documentation for more information .
Hope this helps !!

When you are working on Connected/Integrated mode, you only need to deploy the build artifact on the CD server, that can be deployed by running below command.
jss deploy files

Whenever jss deploy app command is run, it internally runs both these commands jss deploy items and jss deploy files. On CD server, since there is no need to deploy items, hence only command to run is to deploy files.
Make sure before running above command, you have installed JSS server package on the CD server, that can be downloaded from below link.
https://developers.sitecore.com/downloads/Sitecore_JavaScript_Services/150/Sitecore_JavaScript_Services_1501
Note: Download the appropriate server package for JSS according to Sitecore version.
Hope this helps!!!
